# What to do about wrongly edited code in answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

I know that we shouldn't edit code in questions, for obvious reasons. But what about code in answers? Does the same rule apply?

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249076/1288408) case, the code in the answer was changed by an edit to reflect what the author wrote in the text, but I believe that this is not was the author meant. The edit changed the code to something *that wouldn't even compile*, and after that, downvoting started. As I see it, an edit should make the answer more correct, not introduce further errors.

Wouldn't it have been better to add a comment suggesting the changes? Should this edit be reverted?

I could at least edit it to use Integer instead of int, but that would still change the code, and I am not sure if I should do that.

**Edit:**
Since this wasn't really an edit problem, [but a problem with html rendering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163184/204841), I'll add a picture of what was presented here:

[image: Edit view diff]

On hindsight, `added 6 characters in body` would have been a hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The edit just code-ified the unformatted code. If you look back at the source of the original post, it read:

```
This means that the ArrayList consists of objects that are of type Number.

Since the value you are trying to add is of type int I'd recommend you to change:

private ArrayList<Number> list;

into:

private ArrayList<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();
```

See how the code isn't indented with four spaces? The original post did indeed have the incorrect `ArrayList<int>` bits. But unindented, this renders as:

> This means that the ArrayList consists of objects that are of type Number.
>
> Since the value you are trying to add is of type int I'd recommend you to change:
>
> private ArrayList list;
>
> into:
>
> private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

The `<Number>` and `<int>` parts are interpreted as HTML tags and become invisible. It looks like the original poster just wrote code without generics, but it's actually improper Markdown formatting!

Comment: I am sure it didn't, because I have seen it right when it was posted, and I see `private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();` without <int> in the diff. I am slightly confused :)

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen: the parser interpreted `<int>` as an invalid HTML tag and removed it during the page rendering. You can view the original source here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/152f92b6-2ef6-4194-b6a5-c853e0d4e820/view-source, or click the "side-by-side markdown" button in [the revision list](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14249076/revisions).

Comment: I see, this makes sense. That was the reason I didn't see it in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First off, [as John notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163183/what-to-do-about-wrongly-edited-code-in-answer/163184#163184) the editor in this case didn't break anything - the answer was broken from the get-go, and the edit just made it render properly.

Beyond that, any edit that *improves* a post is generally a good one, but always try to respect the original author: if you find yourself writing something he might have cause to disagree with, post your own answer.

As for what you should do when you come across something like this?

- If you see a *truly malicious edit*, roll it back.
- If you see an edit that makes a post *worse*, roll it back.
- If you see an edit that improves a post, but leaves it with outstanding problems - fix those problems.

Comment: In this case, the edit didn't exactly improve the answer: new ArrayList<int> doesn't compile. Integer would have been correct.

Comment: @Katja: yes, but the original author didn't *write* `ArrayList` - he wrote `ArrayList<int>` but neglected to mark it up. Sometimes, respecting the author means respecting his right to be wrong.